# I want to test if the routes exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I want to test if the routes exist in the component. App should render the specific component on the specific path.

App.js

```
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header jsTrendingTopics={this.props.data} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Dashboard jsTrendingTopics={this.props.data} />} />
          <Route exact
            path="/language/:languagename"
            render={(props) => this.handleTopic(props)
            }
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

I expect the test to return the component that should render on that specific route.

Comment: According to doc you can use matchPath function
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath

Answer (score 0):

I think `MemoryRouter` with `initialEntries={['/]}` is what you are looking for.

```
import Dashboard from ...
jest.mock('path to Dashboard component');


Dashboard.mockImplementationOnce(() => <div>Dashboard</div>);

    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <App/>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

expect(screen.getByText("Dashboard").toBeInTheDocument()
```

You can read this document for more examples
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/testing-react-router-with-jest-bc13d367bad